# Don't understand how to attach digital signatures to make a trade legally binding

Tags: digital-signature

i am working on a web-project where it is required to work with "Digital Signature". I searched the web and this platform and understood the creation of it (public/private key). But i don't understand how to store this signature with an offer into the database. As an example:
If i order something from http://www.amazon.com and decide to not keep the ordered item then, after refunding processed, i receive a mail from Amazon also stating that

> A qualified digital signature was attached to this electronic tax refund.

Note: This line was translated from German to English.

Now, this seems to be what i want for both the offering user and the buying user. Both signatures must be unique and legally binding. I wonder, what this statement by Amazon means and how i have to visually understand this? How would i have to store such a signature to an offer as a customer and how would i have to store such a signature as a buyer when accepting the offer?

What i thought how to achive this was:
Creating an offer and accepting an offer do not happen simultaniously. Instead, an offer is created and stored in the database until somebody interested wants to accept it. This offer was digitally signed on creation to confirm a buy-acceptance in advance.
The buyer finds the offer, clicks to buy the offered item and must digitally sign this with a signature. The deal is then legally binding stored with both signatures. This shall ensure, that no party can claim to be victim of fraud. The digital signatures shall act as proof that both parties consciously decided to do what they did.

How do the public/private key and the Captcha-like random strings and the offer act together in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you should use an electronic signature platform like DocuSign to have something that verifies that the transaction takes place.  DocuSign can also digitally stamp the final document to make it digitally signed.

You can also get the embedded signing from DocuSign and add that to your app:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I plaid with the DocuSign API and found it to be no solution since the documents are sent to the user via mail first, the user then has to log in to its DocuSign account to sign the document there and then send it back to somewhere. I think i have to state that with 'document' i dont mean a sheet with a 'signature' field. Instead i am talking about a website form, where a user fills data in, and then, before send, must repeat a presented random string into another input to proof, he consciously filled the form. This random unique string shall act as kinda signature.

Comment: It is no good to force the user to login to another website first just to do the signing there. Instead everything must happen on the fly within the presented form.

Comment: actually on the embedded signing the user doesn't know they are going to a different site.  The signing is hosted in an IFRAME.  You do actually want people to go to another services because DocuSign guarantees that the documents have not been tampered with since signing.

Comment: Mabe its cuz i used the introductory example for building my signing class making me think that that's the way it goes in general. An iframe might be an option depending on how it would look and behave like. But, what i didn't get so far: Would i for example need to have 10000 user accounts with DocuSign if i had that much registered users on my site? That would become a pretty much expensive game then. From The docs it's not getting clear to me if the 'user' is us - the registered company - or every single user instance from our users crowd. If so, then an auto-register-task was required too.

Comment: You won't need to get 1000 licenses from DocuSign to get 1000 to sign documents.  Signers can use DocuSign free, it's only the sending that you need to pay for.

Comment: I see. Well, i have to dig a little deeper and try to get the iframe implementation done to get the whole thing in my head. Can you tell me if every user must create a scan of its name and upload it somewhere to use it? If so, i'm afraid our users won't do this. Not everybody has a scanner or the technical knowledge ... not to forget ... the trust in this thing.

Comment: No, every user is guided through adopting a signature.  It's actually very easy and can be done in just a few clicks.  By using DocuSign you will also gain the capability to support mobile devices.  Insofar as the trust I believe you will gain more trust by using DocuSign than by rolling your own.

Comment: I'm pretty much confused after reading through the guides. This document-, template-, envelope-, PDF-thing is making me crazy. Mabe you can draw me an integration example for my specific case and tell me what i am required to have statically and what will be generated dynamically? The scenario: A user must fill a a form on a website - fill in the begin and end date of a date period and check a checkbox to agree to the ToC. These selections must then be confirmed / signed in place.

Comment: But, from what i understood so far the kind of embedded integration i want (a button) and the kind of embedded integration i have to expect (http://sample1.docusign.com/embeddocusign.php) are miles apart. And the longer i read your guides just to find out if i'm wrong, the more i'm getting confused. This topic seems hardcore to me. The ideal integration was just a button to be clicked and all the rest happens silently behind the curtain.

Comment: Tino, if you want a legally binding process you can't just have a button. You need to let the user review the text and agree to it.  If you are OK with something not being legally binding you can just have a checkbox.  Have you talked to our account managers or sales engineers?  They can walk you through it.

Comment: Nope, didn't know you were related to DocuSign. I think i should follow this advice.